# Are instantiated classes unique for each user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, instantiation

Given the following masterpage or content page ...............

```
namespace Intranet
{
    public partial class Site : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        WebSite.Security.Users.CurrentUser currentUser;

        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                currentUser = new WebSite.Security.Users.CurrentUser();
                currentUser = WebSite.Security.Users.GetCurrentUser(currentUser);
                Label_UserId.Text = currentUser.UserId;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

that calls the following ............

```
namespace Intranet
{
    public class WebSite
    {
        public class Security
        {
            public class Users
            {
                public class CurrentUser
                {
                    public string UserId { get; set; }
                }
                public static CurrentUser GetCurrentUser(CurrentUser cu)
                {
                    cu.UserId = "MethodThatGetsUserId";
                    return cu;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Will the returned instantiated class 'currentUser' contain unique information even if several different users are on the page at the same time?

Thanks for your time and insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, with this line:

```
 currentUser = new WebSite.Security.Users.CurrentUser();
```

You are creating a new instance in your master page class. Instances created in each `request` are only available in that request (of course, depending on the scope), unless you use `static` variables. Static variables are the same for `all users/threads` in your application.

However, what you actually want to do is to get the current user. This should be done using the `HttpContext.Current.User` or `Page.Current` which is an `IPrincipal` and should contain information you filled in the `Authenticate_Request` method of your application.

To understand more about the ASP.NET forms authentication, please refer to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9wff0kyh(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: The properties of the CurrentUser class contains many more fields then just userid (which is populated HttpContext), and I wanted one place to set/get all user information.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a new class is instantiated for each request even, not just each user.

Static fields in the class will be shared, and you should use session and application data to share data across requests or users.

Comment: So when the properties were static and i was instantiating the class in the code file, that was why userid's were being shared across different users when they were visiting pages that called those static properties?

Is how I did it at the very top how you would store and access properties during a pages life? I know I can use session variables, but I love the intellisense part of using classes this way.

Comment: @user3071434 you can still use your strongly typed class as long as your class that you pass in to the session state is serializeable.